# Problem in retrieving my password

Tags: facebook

I am trying to retrieve my password for a newer Facebook account via email, but my old account was originally activated under that same email address.

Recently, I lost my phone and the number with which I had logged in to Facebook with the newer account is now deactivated.

How can I retrieve the password for the newer account via email so that I can log in and use the account?

Comment: I think I have captured the essence of what you were originally saying, but feel free to re-edit anything that I have misinterpreted.

Comment: .@user131583: To answer this I need more information. Is there any email id was associated with your new account or you were using it only with phone number? Currently your old account is activated or deactivated or deleted?

Comment: @user131583: No need to write your personal information here. You can delete your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so when you are trying to retrieve password for your new account, it is activating your old deactivated account.

If this is the case, let activate your old account and change the email id for this account. Once you changed the email id of old account, your email id (sh*****9@gmail.com) will be free. You can deactivate your old account again after changes.

Now if your email id (sh*****9@gmail.com) is associated with new account, you can retrieve the password using the email id. It will not activated the old account.